# disable a control in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have create and edit screens for a entity. They only differ by one control, i.e, a text box appears in middle of edit screen. I wanted to create a partial view for these pages but how to disable the textbox control for create screen. I am already passing a object to the partial view but how to pass additional information to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap it in a conditional statement based on the Unique Identifier of the item you are creating or editing; assuming that the unique id will be something like 0, -1 or null for create and > 1 for existing items...